# download jdk1.5.0_18 source code

Tags: java

I'm looking for the JDK source code for Java 1.5 update 18 (on win XP). I don't want to install a JDK, I don't want the source code for the entire VM, just the source for the JDK libs, so that when I navigate to a Java class in Eclipse, it opens up the source code.

Is it possible to download just src.zip (or a zip that contains src.zip)? I don't want to install a new JDK/JRE just to get access to src.zip as I'm concerned that this will have undesirable side-effects such as modifying JAVA_HOME.

Thanks,
Don

Comment: Maybe you just want to browse them online? Try searching classes at [KickJava](http://kickjava.com/).

Comment: No, I want to download them so I can navigate to them in Eclipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best place to go to get old versions of Java stuff is the [Archive](http://java.sun.com/products/archive/) page.  JDK 1.5.0_18 is there.

However, I don't think it is possible to download *just* the source code ZIP file.  But hey, you could always get a friend to download the relevant JDK and copy it onto a CD/DVD for you.

**EDIT** re your concern about environment variables being changed.

Installing a JDK does not modify the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable or any other environment variable.  Indeed, the JDK / JRE installation instructions explain that you need to update `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` manually.

Sun have always been careful to allow you to install multiple JDK/JREs side-by-side.  The only thing of that nature that gets changed by the installer is the version of Java used by your browser's Java plugin.  And that only changes *if you give the installer permission to change it!!*

Answer (score 1):

Below is the source for the latest JDK 1.5 but it seems difficult to find update 18 specifically, at least there is no obvious link :-(
http://java.sun.com/j2se/jrl_download.html

Answer (score 1):

Only place I know of that you can get them is with the JDK.  You can grab it [here](http://java.sun.com/products/archive/j2se/5.0_18/index.html)
Installing it shouldn't modify JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Download the JDK for the release you want to use, and install it.

Then start Eclipse and go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs, and Add the JDK you just installed, and ensure it has the checkmark!

That should do it (and it doesn't mess with the default java versions and JAVA_HOME and all)